# highcharts reset zoom on master detail graph

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I've set up a master detail chart that doesn't verge too far from the example on the highcharts api demo site (http://www.highcharts.com/demo/dynamic-master-detail).

When adding:

```
resetZoomButton: {
                    position: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: -15
                    }
                 }
```

to the detail chart, it fails to bring up a reset zoom button.  Is there a way of resetting the zoom on a master-detail graph?

my JSFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/sBEMS/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can prepare your own button with position absolute and appropriate coordinates. Then fire click event and set appropriate range by setExtremes() function.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes()